# Where do you deploy your Django application online?

Tags: django, django-deployment

I'm developing a web application with django. I used to use Openshift to publish/deploy my work. What do you think is the best platform? My only requisite is to have an usable and scalable free plan. Then when things comes bigger I will pay.

Answer (score 5):

AWS is good and you can start play it for free. It's highly scalable. Google also has the same service that you can use for free (google give you 300$ to start)

- AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/
- Google Platform: https://cloud.google.com/

Another cheap alternative is digitalocean: http://www.digitalocean.com.

If you don't want a VPS and you prefer a shared hosting, webfaction is good enough, but not so scalable as having a VPS. http://www.webfaction.com

Answer (score 0):

[Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) is amazing cloud application platform for Django apps (not only). Build tools & systems, Scalability, Pipelines, Visual test runner, Addons and services. You must try it! Simple, flexible pricing for everyone!